# Prove that $f\cdot g^2/(f^2+g^2)$ is differentiable if $f$ and $g$ are.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

Let $f,g\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable functions. Is it true that the function $h\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$
h(x) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{f(x)g(x)^2}{f(x)^2+g(x)^2} & \text{if } (f(x),g(x)) \neq (0,0) \\
0 & \text{if } (f(x),g(x)) = (0,0).
\end{cases}
$$

is differentiable everywhere? It is clear that $h$ is differentiable whenever $(f(x),g(x))\neq(0,0)$, by the sum, product and quotient rules. The derivative however is quite messy and it doesn't seem clear how to proceed efficiently to deal with the origin.

Also the function from $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$
$$(x,y)\mapsto \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2}$$
is not differentiable at the origin, so an approach which uses the chain rule seems unlikely to work. An elementary solution not invoking heftier theorems, such as L'Hospitals's rule, would be preferred.

Comment: Why do you want to think about this as a function of several variables - all are functions of $x$. This is differentiable because the denominator is always positive, and sums, products, and quotients are all differentiable when their terms are differentiable.

Comment: The denominator is zero when $f(x)=g(x)=0$.

Comment: Right, but this only happens if $f$ and $g$ both vanish at the same $x$. And if this is the case, the numerator also vanishes. Have you tried L'Hospital's rule? Intuitively, whatever speed $f$ and $g$ go to 0 at, the denominator goes to $0$ at the larger of the two, while the numerator goes to $0$ at speed equal to the product, so L'Hospital should work.

Comment: Hmm L'Hospital's Rule seems like a bit much, I'd expect there to be a simpler proof.

Comment: The reason why I brought up the function of several variables is that this is an interesting example of a function from $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ which is not differentiable at the origin, but is differentiable along any differentiable path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $f(0)=g(0)=0$. Then 
$$h(x)=f(x)\>{g^2(x)\over f^2(x)+g^2(x)}$$ is continuous at $0$, and $h(0)=0$. As $f$, $g$ are differentiable there are continuous functions $\phi$ and $\psi$ such that
$$f(x)=x\phi(x),\quad \phi(0)=f'(0),\qquad  g(x)=x\psi(x),\quad \psi(0)=g'(0)\ .$$
It follows that
$${f(x)g^2(x)\over f^2(x)+g^2(x)}=x\>\phi(x)\>{\psi^2(x)\over\phi^2(x)+\psi^2(x)}=:x\> \Phi(x)\ .$$
If $(\phi(0),\psi(0))\ne(0,0)$ the limit $\lim_{x\to0}\Phi(x)$ obviously exists. If $\phi(0)=\psi(0)=0$ then $\lim_{x\to0}\Phi(x)=0$ since the large fraction is $\leq1$ and $\lim_{x\to0}\phi(x)=0$.

It follows that your function $h$ is not only continuous but even differentiable at $0$.